# How do you fix Parse error on input ‘->’ on Haskell?

Tags: haskell

The code below is for a calculator I have written. I am trying to handle parse error and token error but I keep receiving the same error on ∖s -> tokens s    How do I fix this? Why do I keep getting this error?

```
 {- main -}
 main = do cs <- getContents
           putStr $ unlines $ map show $
            map (∖s -> tokens s >= parse >= eval) $ lines cs
```

Comment: Your code is not properly indented. `cs` and `putStr` should start on exactly the same column.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is a subtle one. The correct syntax is `\s -> tokens s >= parse >= eval`, using a backslash: `\` U+005C REVERSE SOLIDUS. However, instead your code is `∖s -> tokens s >= parse >= eval`. This is subtly different: instead of using a backslash as expected, it instead uses `∖` U+2216 SET MINUS. Simply use the correct character, by replacing `∖` with `\`, and it should parse correctly.